# R : Plot a line across all plots on par

Tags: r, par

Is there any way to display the red vertical line on both plots?

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
tcplot(dataarr)
abline(v=22150,col="red")
```

Outputs

[image: Threshold Stability Plot]

Comment: what package are you using? there might be a parameter that lets you select which plot to show, so you can do `plot(data, which = 1); abline(); plot(data, which = 2); abline(); etc`

Answer (score -1):

You can use abline(v=22150,col="red",xpd=TRUE) in the call to abline to extend the line past the plot area.

Comment: Doesn't work, only extends the current plot. 
http://imgur.com/Ft0wlve